# Code: EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND; Message: The resource '<projectID>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to import OVA with the following command:

```
gcloud beta compute instances import instance --source-uri=gs://abc/xyz.ova --compute-service-account user@serviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com --os=centos-7
```

Getting error saying -compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com not found

Following is the error message:

```
[import-disk-1]: 2021-05-12T13:40:22Z Finished creating Google Compute Engine disk
[import-disk-1]: 2021-05-12T13:40:22Z Inspecting disk for OS and bootloader
[import-disk-1]: 2021-05-12T13:41:56Z Inspection result=elapsed_time_ms:93608
[import-disk-1]: 2021-05-12T13:42:13Z Making disk bootable on Google Compute Engine
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:24Z step "create-instance" run error: operation failed &{ClientOperationId: CreationTimestamp: Description: EndTime:2021-05-12T07:23:24.254-07:00 Error:0xc000080690 HttpErrorMessage:BAD REQUEST HttpErrorStatusCode:400 Id:3961720838234200610 InsertTime:2021-05-12T07:23:09.145-07:00 Kind:compute#operation Name:operation-5c222bfe9828a-4022eae2 OperationType:insert Progress:100 Region: SelfLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/abcxyz-149810/zones/us-central1-a/operations/operation-5c222bfe9828a-4022eae2 StartTime:2021-05-12T07:23:09.145-07:00 Status:DONE StatusMessage: TargetId:8909656942867536419 TargetLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/abcxyz-149810/zones/us-central1-a/instances/somename-instancep2 User:<projID>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com Warnings:[] Zone:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/abcxyz-149810/zones/us-central1-a ServerResponse:{HTTPStatusCode:200 Header:map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Wed, 12 May 2021 14:23:24 GMT] Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]]} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}:
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:24Z Cleaning up.
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:24Z Deleting content of: gs://abcxyz-149810-ovf-import-bkt-us-central1/5dx29/ovf/
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:24Z Deleting gs://abcxyz-149810-ovf-import-bkt-us-central1/5dx29/ovf/abcxyz-remote-11.31p2-gcp-disk1.vmdk
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:24Z Deleting gs://abcxyz-149810-ovf-import-bkt-us-central1/5dx29/ovf/abcxyz-remote-11.31p2-gcp-file1.iso
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:24Z Deleting gs://abcxyz-149810-ovf-import-bkt-us-central1/5dx29/ovf/abcxyz-remote-11.31p2-gcp.mf
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:24Z Deleting gs://abcxyz-149810-ovf-import-bkt-us-central1/5dx29/ovf/abcxyz-remote-11.31p2-gcp.ovf
[import-ovf]: 2021-05-12T14:23:25Z step "create-instance" run error: operation failed &{ClientOperationId: CreationTimestamp: Description: EndTime:2021-05-12T07:23:24.254-07:00 Error:0xc000080690 HttpErrorMessage:BAD REQUEST HttpErrorStatusCode:400 Id:3961720838234200610 InsertTime:2021-05-12T07:23:09.145-07:00 Kind:compute#operation Name:operation-5c222bfe9828a-4022eae2 OperationType:insert Progress:100 Region: SelfLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/abcxyz-149810/zones/us-central1-a/operations/operation-5c222bfe9828a-4022eae2 StartTime:2021-05-12T07:23:09.145-07:00 Status:DONE StatusMessage: TargetId:8909656942867536419 TargetLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/abcxyz-149810/zones/us-central1-a/instances/somename-instancep2 User:<projID>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com Warnings:[] Zone:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/abcxyz-149810/zones/us-central1-a ServerResponse:{HTTPStatusCode:200 Header:map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Wed, 12 May 2021 14:23:24 GMT] Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]]} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}:  Code: EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND; Message: The resource '<projID>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.
```

Any suggestion on this.

Comment: Does the service account exist in the project with required roles?

Answer (score 0):

The resource - **'projectid-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount'** was not found-

-the Error is occurring if the default compute service account was somehow deleted.

This **'projectID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'** is the Compute Engine default service account. You can check if this service account is present or not by Navigating to your IAM and Admin page in cloud console.

I was able to get this error by deleting my default compute service account and attempting to create an instance through the Cloud Shell, so I assume this is the issue.

If the default compute service account was somehow deleted unknowingly and if it has been less than 30 days, you can restore the account by using this command:

**gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete [ACCOUNT_ID]**

you can refer this [Manage service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting).

After doing the above step, you will have to go API and services page and disable and re-enable the compute engine API. This will take a few moments, but after the GCE(Google Compute Engine) API is re-enabled you should be able to [import your ova file](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files) using the cloud shell.

[gcloud beta compute instances import public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/import#--compute-service-account)

Comment: I couldn't find 'projectID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' in the service-accounts list. I tried run "gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete [ACCOUNT_ID]" but no luck. When I ram undelete command (gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete <projectID>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) getting error saying "ERROR: (gcloud.beta.iam.service-accounts.undelete) Invalid value for [account_id]: Account unique ID should be a number. Please double check your input and try again."

Comment: this means your  service account for compute engine is deleted or it is not enabled in your project, Enable the Compute Engine ApI and wait for some time ,it will work

Comment: Account unique ID is the Id present in the service account , for that undelete command to run you need to provide unique ID, since you dont have that you can enable the Compute Engine ApI

Comment: When I ran the command "gcloud services list --enabled" I could see compute.googleapis.com in the list, but still stuck at the same place. Any suggestion on this.

Comment: you need to have the compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com service account not googleapis.com one,  search and enable the comupte engine API